# Aligning figure to the left side of the double column document

Tags: graphics, horizontal-alignment

I am writing an article which has two columns (according to IEEE style). The problem is related to the aligning of figures. My figures that are on the left column overlap some text present on the right column. If those figures are aligned to the left side then my problem can be solved because I do not want to reduce the size of the pictures. Please guide me how can I solve this problem. In the following I have written a portion of the code which I am using for figures in my latex file. Thanks in advance.

```
\documentclass[journal,comsoc]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\ifCLASSINFOpdf
\usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}
\else
\fi
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\interdisplaylinepenalty=2500
\usepackage[cmintegrals]{newtxmath}
\usepackage{algorithmic} 
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage[caption=false,font=footnotesize]{subfig}
\begin{document}





\begin{figure}
\centering  
\includegraphics[width=4in, height=2.5in, angle=0]{fig6}
\caption{Figure 6.}
\label{fig_sim}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Can you show a full minimal working example (in particular the preamble)?

Comment: @NathanMusoke do you mean the packages that I used? Sorry for asking but I am new and do not know much about latex

Comment: In general it is not a good idea to specify both the width and the height of an image, a this might distort the aspect ratio. I would simply use `\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{fig6}`. If you want your image to be left aligned, why are you centring it?

Comment: @samcarter I have removed \centering but still there is no change in the produced document. That's I have not removed it

Comment: [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) might help you in clarifying your question.

Comment: @FrankMoses I assumed that it would not solve the problem, it is just non-logical. My best guess would be that there is not enough room for the image, therefore my suggestion to use `width=\textwidth`.

Comment: @NathanMusoke I have edited my question according to your advice

Comment: @samcarter I used \textwidth but it has become more worse.

Comment: Problem solved by changing width from 4 to 3.5in

Comment: @FrankMoses good, but even better would be using `\columnwidth` as @samcarter demonstrates in their answer. This will stay correct even if you change page size/margins/etc.

Comment: @NathanMusoke that's true. I have changed it to column width. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Based on your code, I get an perfectly left aligned image, which is obviously too big and therefore overlaps the text in the right hand column. [You can also notice the aspect ration to be distorted, because both `width` and `height` had been specified].

[image]

Resizing the image to the width of the column solves the overlapping problem.

```
\documentclass[journal,comsoc]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}

\lipsum[2]

\begin{figure}[thb]
\centering  
\includegraphics[width=\columnwidth]{example-image}
\caption{Figure 6.}
\label{fig_sim}
\end{figure}

\lipsum

\end{document}
```

[image]

If this makes the image too small, you might want to change it to an image spanning both columns.